# Proving $p = 2$ Norm Satisfies Paralellogram Law

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, normed-spaces

The parallelogram law is given by $$ \lVert x-y \rVert_p^2 + \lVert x+y \rVert_p^2 = 2 \big (\lVert x \rVert_p^2 + \lVert y \rVert_p^2 \big )$$ And the $p = 2$-norm is given by $ \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^k |x_i|^2 \bigg )^{1/2}$

So writing the LHS of the equation gives $$ \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i-y_i|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i+y_i|^2   $$ and the RHS is $$ 2 \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^k |x_i|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^k |y_i|^2 \bigg )$$     However I don't see how to rewrite LHS to make it equal RHS? There is no way as far as I can see to add the terms directly so perhaps I need to use a different approach?

Comment: Do you know how to expand $(a+b)^{2}$ and $(a-b)^{2}$?

Comment: Yes but I can't add absolute value terms directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

For real numbers $a,b$
$$
|a+b|^2 = (a+b)^2 = a^2 +b^2 +2ab,\qquad \text{and}\qquad |a-b|^2 = (a-b)^2 = a^2 +b^2 -2ab,
$$

Comment: Ty, this is what I was missing. Don't know why I was downvoted on such a straightforward question.

Comment: Well, because it is straightforward, you should have tried a little bit more

Comment: Asking questions others think is simple shouldn't be punished. I wasn't aware of the rule you posted so I couldn't get anywhere trying to combine the terms so I was stuck and therefore posted a question. I don't see the issue in asking for help whenever you are stuck regardless of how "simple" the problem may be to others with more experience.